# is it good idea to store images in Spring mvc real path

Tags: spring-mvc, path

is it good idea to  store images in the following location of project

```
String realPath  = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/"+studentDetails.getFirstname()+".png");
```

for this i am getting location of image as follows

```
'F:\spring\springUdemyWorkpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\campasAdmin\resources\images\sandy.png'
```

> 1.will it cause any problem in the project production in real time as we deploy into other server ?

please tell me that is it good idea to do so ?

**EDIT**

we need to get that image and show when needed.
and images also get updated when needed.

Comment: This is almost certainly not going to work well.  But what are you actually trying to do with this path?  And these resources?  Are they static resources you are trying to serve back to a web client?  Are they dynamic and you trying to upload and store them for later use?  If you can describe how they are used in the application you are building then we will be able to answer better.

Comment: thank you for replay. i have updated my post please check it.

Comment: OK.  Are you using Spring Boot?  Or just Spring-MVC?

Comment: i am using Spring-MVC